# hour must be in 0..23: 27:33.5 and dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns] errors

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am using a GPS data in which I have a time column  I first want to convert the str time column to the datetime format and then again convert it to the datetimeindex format to perform the resample

when  I try to convert it to the datetime format using  from str `dt["time] = pd.datetime(dt["time])` 
but it gives error saying
ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 27:33.5

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYsA3.png)

I used

```py
df['time'] =  pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'])
```

but it does not allow me to convert it further to the datetimeindex format as I need to do resample in next step.

Comment: values like "27:33.5" to me seem to be durations, not time (as on a clock) - so parsing to timedelta seems appropriate. You can add the timedelta column to a reference date to get datetime.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.